# How to add a side menu in app within three20?

Tags: three20, sidebar

I'm using three20 framework in my app,but I don't know how to add a side menu(like path or facebook) in it within three20 framework.
any one can help me?
thx a lots.

Answer (score 0):

[DDMenuController](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController) is pretty easy to implement.

[image: DDMenuController]

Comment: thank u for your comment,but i don't know how to use DDMenuController in three20